# Remove elements before ajax execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an html page with hidden template containers which is used by JavaScript to add new sections to the html page.

These containers/sections contains input fields that I wish to send via ajax to a php server.

I wish to remove the template containers from the html page before sending the input fields with ajax since I do not want the data from the template containers.

When I try removing the template containers from the html page before the ajax execution, it seems like JavaScript cannot find the data anymore.

I have a workaround but I'm trying to understand why this is happening.

```
function submitData(){      
    let templates = document.getElementById("template-container");
    templates.remove();
    let data = getData();
    let dataHTMLJsonString = JSON.stringify(data);

    let doIt = true;
    if (doIt){
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "processes/writefile.php",
            data: {dataHTML: dataHTMLJsonString},
            cache: false,
            success: function(){
                alert("5x15 Sent");
                document.body.appendChild(templates);
            }
        });
}
```

The HTML

```
<!-- Real data -->
<div class="customer-input-container">
<label>Customers</label>
<select name="customers" class="customer-input" bold="true">                        
    <option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option> 
</select>
</div>

<!-- Template data -->
<div class="customer-input-container" id="template-container">
<label>Customers</label>
<select name="customers" class="customer-input" bold="true">                        
    <option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option> 
</select>
</div>
```

The JavaScript

```
function getData{
    tmpData = "";
    sectionData = document.getElementsByClassName("customer-input");
    for(i = 0; i <= section.length; i++){
        tmpData += sectionData[i].value;
    }
}
```

Comment: You delete sections before ajax and want to show after success, do i understand correct?

Comment: Can you swap `templates.remove()` and `let data = getData();`

Comment: Can you show us the method getData()?

Comment: @RubenDanielyan yes

Answer (score 0):

`getData()` uses the DOM to get the informations. So you are getting a reference to the template DOM element, then you remove it from the DOM and now the data is not there anymore..

```
let templates = document.getElementById("template-container");
templates.remove();
let data = getData();
let dataHTMLJsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
```

I would rewrite it to something like this:

```
let templates = document.getElementById("template-container");
let data = getDataFromTemplates(templates); // explicits the dependency on the DOM
let dataHTMLJsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
templates.remove();
```

And inside `getData` you could use `templates.getElementsByClassName("customer-input")`

Comment: I updated my question so you can see snippets of my HTML and JS. What I don't understand is that I'm only removing the template container from the DOM the other real input fields still remains. My workaround is actually what you are suggesting (but you have it in reverse, I don't want the template data, only the real data). So even though I have a solution, I'm still wondering my original code is not working.

Comment: How do you insert real data in html? And what happens if you add a console.log(sectionData[i], i) in getData inside the for loop